# How do you listen for clicks on POI using Google Maps API?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

By default a Google Map embedded using the API (V3) has all sorts of points of interest scattered across it, just like on maps.google.com. These are mostly for parks, businesses, schools etc. Like a Marker you can click them to reveal an info window, but unlike a marker I don't have a reference to them as I didn't create them myself. That being the case, is there a way to listen for click events on these elements?

Comment: nice suggestion, but seems Google Maps API has no such function yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking into this some more and searching through the entire [Maps API reference](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html) it seems this is indeed unsupported, at least in the current API version (3.8)